# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for validation against siblings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to accept `ScheduledTime` records for `Content`.  ie `Content` can have many `ScheduleTime`.

I would like to validate `ScheduledTime` against their siblings.  Examples:

- a `ScheduledTime` can not be set within 30 minutes of another.
- a limited amount of `ScheduledTime` can be create per Content per day.

I can write a custom validator that does this by querying against the database, and that works fine inserting a single record at a time.

But it appears that with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` validations are done on all new records before any are inserted, rather then validate first, insert, next insert etc.

Is there any way to get Rails to insert after each validation or do I have to manually iterate the params and insert?

Comment: Did you have any luck on getting this to work? Having a similar issue with uniqueness validation. I know I can write a custom validator on the parent to have it check the siblings, but that feels more heavy handed.

Comment: No luck finding a good solution for this.  I ended up writing a custom validator.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did too. Nested attributes has tended to be a mixed bag.